# Как вырезать несколько столбцов из csv файла и сохранить в другой файл?

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

Подскажите, как вырезать несколько столбцов из одного CSV-файла и сформировать новый CSV-файл, состоящий только из этих столбцов?
Требуются 4, 5, 7, 11 столбцы. Разделитель ','.

Comment: Что значит записать их в другой? Сформировать новый csv, состоящий только из этих столбцов? Или добавить их в уже существующий?

Comment: Сформировать новый csv, состоящий только из этих столбцов

Comment: а столбцы имеют заголовки?

Answer (score 2):

Если столбцы у вас именованы, например 'company, 'price', product' и так далее, то всё просто. Вот скрипт, который я использую для вырезания данных, которые нужны лаборанту:

```
# Папка, где лежат данные, можно переделать, чтобы вводить в качестве аргумента
$inp = 'H:\result\csv_data\current\'

# Флэшка лаборанта, всегда L :) тоже можно переделать
# и вообще, если вам нужен конкретный файл, сразу используйте его, а не циклите
$out = 'L:\'

# выборка столбцов
$cols = 'date','pacient_name', 'status','level'

# циклим по файлам в папке
Get-ChildItem $folderPath -Name |


ForEach-Object { 

    $fileinp = $inp + $_


    $fileout = $out + $_

    # выбираем столбцы, записываем их в новый файл на флэшку
    Import-Csv $fileinp | Select $cols |
    Export-Csv -Path $fileout –NoTypeInformation
}
```

Если же столбцы у вас не разыменованы, то придётся заняться этим, и скрипт придётся переделать. Он после этого будет выполняться дольше:

```
# Папка, где лежат данные, можно переделать, чтобы вводить в качестве аргумента
$inp = 'H:\result\csv_data\current\'

# Флэшка лаборанта, всегда L :) тоже можно переделать
# и вообще, если вам нужен конкретный файл, сразу используйте его, а не циклите
$out = 'L:\'

# выборка столбцов, вам нужны 4,5,7,11
$cols = 'four','five', 'seven','eleven'

# циклим по файлам в папке
Get-ChildItem $folderPath -Name |


ForEach-Object { 

    $fileinp = $inp + $_


    $fileout = $out + $_

    # выбираем столбцы, записываем их в новый файл на флэшку
    # поскольку последний из нужных столбцов - одиннадцатый, я беру максимум 11 столбцов
    Import-Csv $fileinp -header one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven | Select $cols |
    Export-Csv -Path $fileout –NoTypeInformation
}
```

В целом, если вам не нужны пляски с папками, а нужно просто таким образом обработать один файл, сохраните нижеприведенный скрипт, например, с именем select.ps1 и далее используйте как **select.ps1 имя_входного_файла.csv имя_выходного_файла.csv**

```
$cols = 'four','five', 'seven','eleven'
Import-Csv $args[0] -header one,two,three,four,five,six,seven,eight,nine,ten,eleven | Select $cols |
Export-Csv -Path $args[1] –NoTypeInformation
```

P.S. Напомню, что в Windows 10/Server 16 (и, возможно, server 12) powershell пошлёт вас подальше без разрешения выполнения скриптов.  Чтобы справиться с этим, разрешите скрипты на время сессии через  `Set-ExecutionPolicy`, при этом powershell должен быть с правами админа. Не забудьте затем отменить разрешение.

P.P.S. Чисто из врожденного злорадства: консольное приложение, написанное на Delphi, делает подобное преобразование в 7.5 раз быстрее, специально замерил :) И разрешения менять не надо :P.